# "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I've put a new (second hand) graphics card (nVidia GT8800) in my PC. I forgot to delete the old drivers first... (nVidia GT8600).

Now I get a warning every 5 minutes or so. "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered". I found A LOT of information on this subject, but none of the sollutions helped me out. I also found that many people didn't get an answer on this error message. Also, the Microsoft support site suggests me some sollutions, but they all won't help.

I already de-installed the GT8600 drivers (show all devices in device manager), and re-installed the GT8800 a couple of times with different versions of drivers, also the latest. When I'm typing this, I didn't get the error, but sometimes it happens A LOT.

When the PC is idle for 2 minutes or so, and I touch the mouse, the screen flickers, and I get the error afterwords.

**Note**: Yesterday I played the game Company Of Heroes for about an hour, without any problem. When I work in Windows 7 (surfing the internet, checking mail, ...) I get this error all the time. The card isn't getting too hot also. (checked that)

Is there a way to know what program is causing this error?

Comment: Are you saying this only happens when using your browser?

Comment: Uninstall the drivers the reinstall the current drivers.  Of course the two graphic cards are from exactly the same series and use exactly the same drivers.

Comment: @screamingSiLENCE check out the MS article for ["Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7 or Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946). hope it will help you.

Comment: Maybe a PSU problem?

Comment: Avirk, I've seen that article already, didn't help...

Comment: The problem happens more when I'm browsing. But it also happens when I'm doing other things. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Desktop fix: Go into your hardware, and reconnect your graphics card. The GPU is one of the most easiest parts of the computer to replace/reconnect. If that doesn't work, see what GPU's are compatible with your desktop, and buy a new one. =/

Laptop fix: Flashing the BIOS if probably one of your only options. I ONLY SUGGEST THIS OPTION IF YOU'RE PREPARED TO BUY A NEW LAPTOP IN CASE THIS MESSES UP YOUR COMPUTER. It's a last resort for laptops, but if you've already tried re installing drivers, than this may work. Flashing the bios resets almost all of the BIOS settings and updates the motherboard. BIOS is kind of like the software that manages your motherboard. Your graphics card is almost always connected to your motherboard under a PCIx16 slot. If you flash the BIOS it will normally reset the PCIx16 slot as well. You can find a guide for flashing/updating the BIOS here: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/03/what-is-flashing-the-bios/

Updating the BIOS can also solve a lot of compatibility problems with graphics cards, discrete sound cards, ect. Again, I can't stress enough of how DANGEROUS it is to mess with some stuff in the BIOS. Your problem sounds a lot like a graphics hardware problem, so I don't expect flashing/updating the BIOS. But if you're going to get a new laptop 'cause the graphics card is messed out, try the flashing/updating first.